# SharedPreferences Default mode

Tags: java, android, android-sharedpreferences

What is the Mode Default Value for `PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(context)`?

How can I make The DeafaultSharedPreference Private?

Comment: Well, How Can I get The Default Shared Preference By "getSharedPreferences" method?

Answer (score 3):

`SharedPreferences` are private by default.

```
public static final int MODE_PRIVATE 
getSharedPreferences("pref", MODE_PRIVATE);
```

read more about **[SharedPreferences](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/data/data-storage.html#pref)** and **[SharedPreferences](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/SharedPreferences.html)**